# Benefits of Parallel programming

Tags: java, c++, parallel-processing

I have three similar questions:

1. Which known applications have benefits of multicore processors?
2. Which known applications use posix threads (pthreads)?
3. What can pthreads do that Java threads cannot?

Comment: 1) Do you want names of actual applications, or types of applications?
2) Likewise.

Comment: Java threads suck, pthread threads do NOT :-)

Comment: @Malkocoglu: pthreads suck, Java threads do NOT :-) Why do you say that Java threads suck? At least Java has synchronization built-in into the language which makes it a lot easier.

Comment: @Jesper: Back in the day, Java had something called green threads which were not real threads. Java synchronized keyword locks the class object which is not generally a good thing...

Comment: A lot of games rely on multithreading

Comment: @Malkocoglu sorry, but that's largely nonsense. Green threads have been nonexistent since about 1998, and synchronized only locks the class object when you use it as a method modifier on a static method.

Comment: @Michael: It is not Java but some incompetent Java people, because I saw production code running on JVM 1.2 with green threads last year. To me, (I repeat "To me") Java synchronization is much more confusing compared to pthread. (http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/01/28/java-concurrency-bugs-synchronize-object/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to first two questions: most Linux open source projects written in C use pthreads.
For example Apache.
What can pthreads do that java threads cannot?
They can work without Java Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 2):

[answering the first question] Apps which benefit most (and most easily) from multicore processors are server apps which service many clients and have high per-client CPU cost, like web servers, database servers, and other application servers-- and apps which run on top of those servers.  By spreading client load across several processors, as long as those clients aren't contending on shared resources (e.g. shared data, or a disk drive) you'll get a large speedup.

Single-user apps (e.g. batch processing, command-line tools, GUI tools) can also be made to benefit from multicore, but they often must be substantially re-architected to get a big perf win.

BTW, you might want to split #2 and #3 questions out into a separate SO question-- the general question of parallel benefits is pretty different from a Java vs. Posix thread comparison.

Comment: Nice explanation, and do you know name of any application that use parallel programming (pthreads)?

Answer (score 1):

Almost all mainstream desktop applications use multiple threads, so they all get **some** benefit from multiple processors.

The applications that get the most benefit from multiple processors are those that perform huge amounts of independent computations. Audio, Video, and Image processing, for example.

The pthreads and Java programming models are fairly similar, given the obvious differences between Java and C programming. Java is a little bit higher-level, so there ate some features in pthreads that are abstracted a bit in Java. Basically, you can do the same things with both.

Answer (score 0):

I love SMP boxes for batch programming.  Use vintage 1970s unix "pipe" technology:

```
% step1 < some.data | step2 | step3 > some.output
```

Now, that wasn't hard, was it?

Of course, the other comments are true about servers.  You can do some fancy processing by breaking a batch into parallel substeps, but you have to write a "smart" controller to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

> Which known applications have benefits
>   of multicore processors?

Any application that uses multithreading or multiprocessing. One example: Google Chrome uses multiprocessing by dedicating a separate process to each tab window. It benefits from multiple processors if multiple tabs are using CPU resources at the same time. (It also uses multithreading.)

> Which known applications use posix threads (pthreads)?

Posix threads are used on POSIX compliant systems. This usually means Unix or Linux (Mac is posix compliant too, but I'm not sure if Cocoa threads build upon pthreads). Example: Firefox and Google Chrome on Linux.

> What can pthreads do that Java threads cannot?

What can a car steering wheel do that a truck steering wheel cannot? They both do their thing but were where designed to be used on a specific platform.